# (x,y) origin for 3 wheeled robots

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 2-differential drive wheels in front, and caster in rear, of my rectangular platform.  I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on where (x,y) = (0,0) should be in the footprint parameter in the costmap yaml files.  Is it the turn pivot location between the 2 drive wheels or the physical center of the robot frame.  I have seen both used in different posts.  I am using ROS Melodic.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391174/(x,y)-origin-for-3-wheeled-robots/) by [BigBadJohn](https://answers.ros.org/users/89880/bigbadjohn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be mid-way between the two drive wheels. It is at the rotation point when the drive wheels cause the robot to spin in place.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1